# /etc/hosts in debian resets itself on reboot

Tags: debian, alias, hosts

I've been having a problem where when our vps provider decides to restart the server (running Debian 5.0.8), the server fails to remember changes to `/etc/hosts`.  All I need is an database alias that is used for the web applications on the server which points to `127.0.0.1` (`localhost`).

I want it to look like this:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
# (added automatically by netbase upgrade)

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts


127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost webservice database
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
XXX.XX.XXX.XX xxxxxx.net.au  xxxxxx www.xxxxxxx.net.au xxxxxxx
```

However whenever there is a reboot it resets itself to:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
# (added automatically by netbase upgrade)

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts


127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost webservice
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
XXX.XX.XXX.XX xxxxxx.net.au  xxxxxx www.xxxxxxx.net.au xxxxxxx
```

without the database, and I have to manually change the file to get things to work.  This has been happening for awhile and has become a nuisance, but I can't seem to find a way to get changes to stick.  Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Are you using a VPS?

Comment: @zclark I do not see any difference between the two files you mentioned.Is that a type error or there is some thing which I missed?

Comment: Yeah I'm using a VPS.  The difference in the files is that I add "database" to the end of the line starting with 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @zclark Do you happen to have Network Manager or something similiar running?
It does have some strange ideas wrt the 127.0.0.1-line. Otherwise,
I’d suspect your hosts’ script doing strange stuff, as it already
seems to be tampering with your /etc/hosts (# Auto-generated
hostname. Please do not remove this comment.).

Comment: @zclark  Try adding a new line
pointing to "database" like this and see if that persists:

127.0.0.1 database

Comment: I think I have at one point, will try again. Might call the provider tomorrow too.

Comment: Adding a different line didn't solve the problem. I found a similar question where he deleted the #Auto-generated hostname line and it worked. Going to try that.  On another note, was googling for other answers, ppl seem to hijack questions on here: http://fossplanet.com/f12/etc-hosts-debian-resets-itself-reboot-174628/  word for word my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the #Auto-generated hostname line and then making the changes caused whatever was generating the host names to remember it now.  Works for me but this may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because your system uses Cloud-init (https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). To regain control over your hosts file, you have to edit /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg and change manage_etc_hosts from 'true' to 'false'.